# How can I tell how long Solr replications and commits take

Tags: solr

I know that my Solr commitWithin should be set to a greater length than a commit usually takes.

Likewise, in my replicated setup, I guess my pollInterval should be set to something longer than a replication takes.

I can't work out how to see how long commits and replications take though - how do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried having a look at the Solr log file?

Comment: @javanna well yes I looked at that straight after writing the question.  But there's a lot of stuff in there... I was hoping someone could point me straight to the right place as people often confidently talk of how long their commits take but it's never quite clear how they get the info...  (OTOH hand I could be a bit less lazy ;-)

Comment: Well, when you issue a commit you get back from Solr a message which contains the QTime. That's the time spent on the commit itself.

Comment: OK.. simple as that eh?  You don't know any tools anyone's written to create an average or something?  Either way if you create an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send any request to Solr you get back the QTime within the response. That's the time spent on the server to process your request. If you send a commit you'll get the time spent on the commit itself.
If you're using auto-commit you can have a look at the Solr log file to see how long a commit takes. I'm not aware of any other way.
You can also have a look at [solrmeter](http://code.google.com/p/solrmeter/), it allows you to run some performance tests against a running Solr and it shows a nice graph including commit time.
Regarding replication you get some details passing the parameter command=details to the replication handler, but I'm not sure some replication time is there. If not you need to look at your log file again.

Comment: Thanks - solrmeter is what I was looking for!